# Throttling messages from RabbitMQ using RxJava

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, rx-java

I'm using RxJava to pull out values from RabbitMQ. Here's the code:

```
val amqp = new RabbitQueue("queueName")
val obs = Observable[String](subscr => while (true) subscr onNext amqp.next)
obs subscribe (
  s => println(s"String from rabbitmq: $s"), 
  error => amqp.connection.close
)
```

It works fine but now I have a requirement that a value should be pulled at most once per second while all the values should be preserved (so `debounce` won't do since it drops intermediary values).

It should be like `amqp.next blocks thread so we're waiting... (RabbitMQ got two messages in queue) pulled a 1st message... wait 1 second... pulled a 2nd message... wait indefinitely for the next message...`

How can I achieve this using `rx` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option may be to use the [Schedulers API](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Scheduler#using-schedulers) in combination with a [PublishSubject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject#publishsubject) as the observable.

Unfortunately, I don't know Scala syntax but here is the Java version you should be able to convert:

```
RabbitQueue amqp = new RabbitQueue("queueName");
Scheduler.Worker worker = Schedulers.newThread().createWorker();
PublishSubject<String> obs = PublishSubject.create();
worker.schedulePeriodically(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        obs.onNext(amqp.next);
    }
}, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Your subscribe code from above would remain the same:

```
obs subscribe (
  s => println(s"String from rabbitmq: $s"), 
  error => amqp.connection.close
)
```

Comment: This is going to be extremely slow. Relying on polling of the queue (amqp.next) is very inefficient and should only be used for really simple clients that can't handle threading (ie Python). Instead of polling you should rely on the prefetchCount to apply backpressure and use the DefaultConsumer which is asynchronous... but apparently that is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could create a observable from a timer like that. I personally find this more elegant.

```
RabbitQueue amqp = new RabbitQueue("queueName");
Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(tick -> amp.next())
        .subscribe(...)
```